# ViewModel unit testing with Repository + LiveData + Coroutines

Tags: android, unit-testing, kotlin, retrofit

So I'm confused about how to implement the unit testing to my ViewModel. I'm using retrofit for my API fetching and using the repository.

ViewModel.kt

```
@HiltViewModel
class MoviesViewModel @Inject constructor(private val moviesRepository: MoviesRepository) :
ViewModel() {
private val _navigatetoDetail = MutableLiveData<Movies?>()

fun getPopularMovies() = liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
    emit(Resource.loading(null))
    try {
        emit(Resource.success(moviesRepository.getPopularMovies()))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(
            Resource.error(
                null,
                e.message ?: "Unknown Error"
            )
        )
        Log.e("viewModel", "popularMovies error: ${e.message}")
    }
}

fun getMovieDetails(movie_id: String) = liveData(Dispatchers.Default) {
    emit(Resource.loading(null))
    try {
        emit(Resource.success(moviesRepository.getMovieDetails(movie_id)))
    } catch (e: Exception) {
        emit(
            Resource.error(
                null,
                e.message ?: "Unknown Error"
            )
        )
        Log.e("viewModel", "movieDetails error: ${e.message}")
    }
}

fun navigatetoDetail(): LiveData<Movies?> {
    return _navigatetoDetail
}

fun onMovieClicked(movies: Movies?) {
    _navigatetoDetail.value = movies
}

fun onMovieDetailNavigated() {
    _navigatetoDetail.value = null
}
```

Repository.kt

```
class MoviesRepository @Inject constructor(private var apiInterface: ApiInterface) {
init {
    apiInterface = ApiBuilder.createService()
}

suspend fun getPopularMovies() = apiInterface.getPopularMovies()

suspend fun getMovieDetails(movie_id: String) = apiInterface.getMovieDetails(movie_id)

suspend fun getPopularTvShows() = apiInterface.getPopularTvShows()

suspend fun getTvShowDetails(tvshow_id: String) = apiInterface.getTvShowDetails(tvshow_id)
```

apiInterface.kt

```
interface ApiInterface {
@GET("/3/movie/popular?api_key=$API_KEY&language=en-US")
suspend fun getPopularMovies(): Envelope<List<Movies>>

@GET("/3/movie/{movie_id}?api_key=$API_KEY&language=en-US")
suspend fun getMovieDetails(@Path("movie_id") movie_id: String?): Movies

@GET("3/tv/popular?api_key=$API_KEY&language=en-US&page=1")
suspend fun getPopularTvShows(): Envelope<List<TvShows>>

@GET("/3/tv/{tvshow_id}?api_key=$API_KEY&language=en-US")
suspend fun getTvShowDetails(@Path("tvshow_id") tvshow_id: String?): TvShows
```

I already tried to test my ViewModel by making it like this:

```
 @Test
fun testGetPopularMovies() = coroutinesTestRule.testDispatcher.runBlockingTest {
    val moviesList = viewModel.getPopularMovies().value
    viewModel.getPopularMovies().observeForever(observer)
    verify(observer).onChanged(argumentCaptor.capture())
    assertEquals(20, moviesList?.data?.results?.size)
}
```

but it return NullPointerException on ***viewModel.getPopularMovies().observeForever(observer)***

Answer (score 1):

Here is an extension function for waiting for live data result. Create koltin extension function using the below code under your test package.

```
import androidx.annotation.VisibleForTesting
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.Observer
import java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit
import java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException


@VisibleForTesting(otherwise = VisibleForTesting.NONE)
fun <T> LiveData<T>.getOrAwaitValue(
time: Long = 2,
timeUnit: TimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS,
afterObserve: () -> Unit = {}
 ): T {
var data: T? = null
val latch = CountDownLatch(1)
val observer = object : Observer<T> {
    override fun onChanged(o: T?) {
        data = o
        latch.countDown()
        this@getOrAwaitValue.removeObserver(this)
    }
}
this.observeForever(observer)

try {
    afterObserve.invoke()

    // Don't wait indefinitely if the LiveData is not set.
    if (!latch.await(time, timeUnit)) {
        throw TimeoutException("LiveData value was never set.")
    }

} finally {
    this.removeObserver(observer)
}

@Suppress("UNCHECKED_CAST")
return data as T
}
```

Here is sample view model class testing.LoginViewmodel class extends AndroidViewModel instead of ViewModel.

```
import androidx.arch.core.executor.testing.InstantTaskExecutorRule
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import androidx.test.ext.junit.runners.AndroidJUnit4
import com.mymaskreminder.ui.getOrAwaitValue
import org.junit.Assert
import org.junit.Rule
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith

@RunWith(AndroidJUnit4::class)
class LoginViewModelTest {

@get:Rule
var instantExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()


@Test
fun sendLoginRequest() {


    val loginViewModel = LoginViewModel(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())


    loginViewModel.sendLoginRequest("test@gmail.com", "12345")

    //shadowOf(Looper.getMainLooper()).idle()


    val value_error = loginViewModel.loginErrorResponse.getOrAwaitValue()


    Assert.assertEquals(value_error.toString(),
        "Unauthorized !"
    )



}
}
```

Comment: it still returns null at observeForever inside the extension function

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a testCoroutineDispatcher or testCoroutineScope to be able to set scope of your viewModel to scope of testing.
add this class:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CoroutineTestRule : TestWatcher(), TestCoroutineScope by TestCoroutineScope() {

override fun starting(description: Description) {
    super.starting(description)
    Dispatchers.setMain(this.coroutineContext[ContinuationInterceptor] as CoroutineDispatcher)
}

override fun finished(description: Description) {
    super.finished(description)
    Dispatchers.resetMain()
}

}
```

and use in test class:

```
@SmallTest
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner::class)
class BaseRepositoryTest {

    @get:Rule
    var instantTaskExecutorRule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()

    @get:Rule
    var coroutineTestRule = CoroutineTestRule()

}
```

dont forgot use runBlockingTest for test functions. runBlockingTest available on coroutinesTest library:

testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.4.3")

```
 @Test
    fun `success user login`() {
        runBlockingTest {
            viewModel.sendLoginRequest(PHONE_VALID_NUMBER1)
            val result = viewModel.liveData.getOrAwaitValueTest()
            assert(result == LoginViewModel.Views(PHONE_VALID_NUMBER1))

        }
    }
```

also use getOrAwaitValue for observe api result

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are `emitting` value from flow in your unit test / mock.
If you do not emit value then your `LiveData` inside the `ViewModel` will never be set any value because there is nothing to collect .
The code inside `collect` in your view model where you setting value on `LiveData` will not be executed.

Another option is by using `TestDispatcher`
If your are using `StandardTestDispatcher` then you need to call `advanceUntilIdle()` function from to execute coroutines scheduled at test TestCoroutineScheduler.

If you are using `UnconfinedTestDispatcher` then you can remove `advanceUntilIdle()` because it starts executing coroutines eagerly.

coroutine-test library

```
testImplementation("org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-test:1.7.3")
```

Method 1

```
 @Test
fun testMethod1() = runTest {
   val observer = Observer<Result> { result ->
    // put your assert statements here
    }
   viewModel.liveData.observeForever(observer)
   viewModel.fetchSomeData()
   advanceUntilIdle()
   viewModel.liveData.removeObserver(observer)
}
```

Method 2

```
 @Test
    fun testMethod2() = runTest {
        viewModel.fetchSomeData()
        advanceUntilIdle()

        val result = viewModel.liveData.value
      
        assertNotNull(result)
        // Write your assert statements here
    }
```

Method 3

By Using getOrAwaitValue() provided in android architecture components samples

https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/blob/master/LiveDataSample/app/src/test/java/com/android/example/livedatabuilder/util/LiveDataTestUtil.kt

```
@Test
fun testMethod3() = runTest {
    val result = viewModel.liveData.getOrAwaitValue {
       viewModel.fetchSomeData()
       advanceUntilIdle()
    }
     
    assertNotNull(result)
    // put your assert statements here
}
```